# c# dictionary and forloop/writing to text messing up - how to make it go through once and not through every iteration

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary, foreach

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class main
    {
        private static StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\text1.txt", true);
        private static StreamWriter tripWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\text2.txt", true);

        private static void Main()
        {
            WelcomeMenu();
        }
        public static void WelcomeMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Pow Drop Log v1");
            Console.WriteLine("A. Press A to start the trip");
            while (true)
            {
                string enteredWelcome = Console.ReadLine();
                {
                    if (enteredWelcome == "a")
                    {
                        List();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid option");
                        continue;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        public static void WriteToTextFile(string text)
        {
            objWriter.Write(text);
            objWriter.Flush();
        }
        public static void WriteToCurrentTrip(string text)
        {
            tripWriter.Write(text);
            tripWriter.Flush();
        }
        public static void List()
        {
            Stopwatch Triptime = new Stopwatch();
            Triptime.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("You have started the trip");
            Dictionary<string, string> tdItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            tdItems.Add("1", "foo");
            tdItems.Add("2", "bar");
            tdItems.Add("3", "bar");
            tdItems.Add("4", "end");
            while (true)
            {
                string[] items = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                string result = null;
                int result1;
                TimeSpan timeSpan = Triptime.Elapsed; string time = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds);
                foreach (string itemNumber in items)
                {
                    if (tdItems.ContainsKey(itemNumber) && (int.TryParse(itemNumber, out result1)))
                    {
                        result += " + " + tdItems[itemNumber];
                        WriteToTextFile(tdItems[itemNumber] + Environment.NewLine);
                        WriteToCurrentTrip(tdItems[itemNumber] + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    if (!tdItems.ContainsKey(itemNumber) && (int.TryParse(itemNumber, out result1)))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have entered a drop which is not in the database, Try again");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (itemNumber == "end")
                    {
                        Triptime.Stop();
                        Console.WriteLine("End of Trip");
                        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time " + time);
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        WelcomeMenu();
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code seems to be going through each part instead of once.

Say if I typed 1 2 3 in the console, in the text file it would write

foo
foo bar 
foo bar baz 
instead of it writing foo + bar + baz in the first place.

I debugged it and it shows it keeps going through, how would I be able to fix this and make it so it does it correctly?.

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on when we can't run it without making significant changes. Please convert this into a short but *complete* program we can just compile and run.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Edited it with the full code. Sorry if it's really messy and wrong and the wrong flow etc, I've just started a week and a half ago.

Answer (score 2):

This code is very bad, and I recommend basically rewriting it until it is much shorter and simpler.  But if I had to make the smallest change possible to make it print out the right thing, I'd change this:

```
WriteToTextFile(result.Substring(3) + Environment.NewLine);
WriteToCurrentTrip(result.Substring(3) + Environment.NewLine);
```

To this:

```
WriteToTextFile(tdItems[itemNumber] + Environment.NewLine);
WriteToCurrentTrip(tdItems[itemNumber] + Environment.NewLine);
```

EDIT:  For reference, here's roughly how I'd write what you indicated you wanted your `List` function to do, with comments interleaved.  You could make it nicer yet, but this should show you some useful things.  I hope I got the intended behavior right.

```
// StartNew happens to be a quicker way to create and initialize a Stopwatch

Stopwatch triptime = Stopwatch.StartNew();
Console.WriteLine("You have started the trip");

// you can use collection initializer syntax to make it nicer to read when
// you want to add lots of things to a data structure

var tdItems = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "1", "foo" },
    { "2", "bar" },
    { "3", "baz" },
    { "4", "end" },
};

while (true)
{
    string[] items = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

    // you can use format strings to easily customize the stringification
    // of DateTime and TimeSpan objects, see the MSDN docs

    string time = string.Format("{0:c}", triptime.Elapsed);

    List<string> waypoints = new List<string>();

    // it's easiest to first find the destinations your trip has to visit

    foreach (string itemNumber in items)
    {
        if (tdItems.ContainsKey(itemNumber))
            waypoints.Add(tdItems[itemNumber]);
        else
            Console.WriteLine(
              "You have entered a drop which is not in the database...");
    }

    // string.Join is an easy way to avoid worrying about putting an extra
    // "+" at the front or end

    string tripDescription = string.Join(" + ", waypoints);

    // "using" is generally important so you don't hold a lock on the file
    // forever, and it saves you from manually calling "flush" -- it
    // flushes when the writers are disposed at the end of the using block

    using (var objWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\text1.txt", true))
    using (var tripWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\text2.txt", true))
    {
        // WriteLine adds a newline for you

        objWriter.WriteLine(tripDescription);
        tripWriter.WriteLine(tripDescription);
    }

    if (waypoints.Contains("end"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("End of Trip");
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time " + time);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        break;
    }
}

// you'll get the welcome menu again when you return from this function
```

If you break up what your code is doing into small, checkable chunks, it's a lot easier to understand, verify, and debug.  In my version, you can see that it got the right waypoints; then you can see that the description looks right; then you can see that it wrote to the file.  In yours, it's sort of trying to do everything at the same time, so it's harder to work with.

Comment: Oh lord, I only started C# like a week and half ago. Didn't know it would be "Very" bad  - and the amended code prints out it each line. I wanted it so like if a person typed in 1 2 3, it would be foo + bar + baz on one like, if they typed 1 2, it would be foo + bar. At the moment if I did 1 2 3 , it would be first line: foo, second line: foo bar and third line: foo bar baz. Ill update the first code with all of it. Sorry if it's really messy bad code and I've done things wrong!

Comment: The key is to try to make it so that every piece of your code represents a natural concept in the process.  I'll provide an example of how I'd improve it.

Comment: Ah right, Thank's for doing this and helping me! I'm finding it difficult to understand certain things and remembering how to actually code it and the process/structure and where things should go. Everyone says that they went through the same thing, but I'm just worrying that it's just me! :(

Comment: Okay, I loaded this up and for some reason every time I enter a number after I have done "Your trip has started", it keeps on crashing saying that the text file is used by another process. I checked my task manager and nothing else is running which would use it. Possibly the code? Or is it purely my end?

Comment: It's probably because one of your old ones is still running in the background!  I'd check Task Manager.